# Can someone translate this for me?

Tags: translation

http://m.imgur.com/i7FcLqc This is from the top of a container my friend found at work. I was wondering if someone could do a quick, easy translation. I tried to draw it in Google translate, but it didn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

一本萬利 in Traditional characters (as in your image) or 一本万利 in Simplified Chinese, the writing goes from top right to bottom left.

The expression means "small capital, huge gain/profit".

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, gf agrees 一本万利

一 = 1
本=本钱=starting money
万= a lot
利 = gain

If you believe that, you will believe anything! Money for nothing!